# Including from child theme root or else include from parent theme root

Tags: wordpress, file, include, themes

at the moment I am working on a Wordpress theme with a functions.php that will include multiple helper functions files. I want this theme to be very flexible and customizable if a child theme is made based on the theme.

I have this piece of code currently in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpf_contact' );
/**
 * Include the logic/settings for tpl-contact.php.
 *
 * Includes the logic/settings for tpl-contact.php. It will load the child's
 * mail.inc.php first if that is available.
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpf_contact' ) ) {
    function wpf_contact() {

        if ( is_page_template( 'tpl-contact.php' ) && is_child_theme() && file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/wpf/mail.inc.php' ) ) {
            include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/wpf/mail.inc.php' );
        } else {
            include( get_template_directory() . '/inc/wpf/mail.inc.php');
        }

    } // end wpf_contact()
}
```

What the code above does is load mail.inc.php from child if the files exist. If it doesn't load it from the parent theme.

Cause I am having multiple files I want to load like that. I was thinking it there might not be a easier way of doing this? Is there a built in function that does this in WordPress?

Or should I just adjust the above function and add parameter's so it can be used for other files as well? Not sure if this is efficient.

Comment: This question belongs on [wordpress.se].

Comment: Tnx, I have bookmarked it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question directly based on your sample, i would not check to see if the file has been placed in the child theme. If a child-theme developer has customized the file, they can simply declare the function and include their own file (wherever they place it). There is no risk of code duplication because your sample function is simple enough.

Even if you simplified your code for the purposes of placing it here....you can always keep includes wrapped in a very simple function that can be declared by a child theme. This will keep PHP running efficient and not having to check for files all the time.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I totally overlooked that you can simply add the function to the child theme function.php, thanks! If I didn't asked here I would have probably gone with a function that would check if a files exist every time when using a child theme.